# Facebook: Friends' likes / interests return empty even with the appropriate permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, string

I'm trying to access my friends' likes through Facebook Graph API. Some of my friends likes are fetched normally, but the majority return as an empty array.

A few notes:

1. My app has the required friends_likes permission
2. I'm not doing batch requests
3. I can see these friends' likes when accessing the Facebook.com UI normally (not via API)

Does anybody know what's causing a lot of my friends' likes to return as empty?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anybody know what's causing a lot of my friends' likes to return as empty?

Most likely their privacy settings regarding what kind of data apps their friends are using are allowed to access.

https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy -> “Ads, Apps and Websites” -> edit settings -> “How people bring your info to apps they use” -> edit settings

If *“Activities, interests, things I like”* is un-checked in your friend’s settings – then your app will receive no info about their likes, even if you got friends_likes permission.